# Ideal database schema for similar structures

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

In our business application, we have a need to store user or system generated "comments" about a particular entity.  For example, comments can be created about a customer, an order, or a purchase order.  These comments all share many of the same characteristics, with the exception of the referenced entity.

All comments require the date, time, user, and comment text.  They also require a foreign key to the referenced table so that you can look up comments for that particular entity.

Currently the application has a separate table for each type of comment (e.g. customer_comments, order_comments, purchaseOrder_comments).  The schemas of these tables are all identical with respect to the date, time, user and comment text, but each has a FK to the respective table that the comment is for.

Is this the best design or is there a better design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd create a single comment table and then use one intersection table per entity (customer, order, etc.) to link the comment with the entity.

[image]

Comment: I'm with you there.  This is the only one of the currently proposed answers that allows you to place/enforce FK constraints.  I've worked with an equivalent architecture (references to multiple external tables) and at least one process grabbed rows belonging to the wrong relationship.

Comment: Yes, I believe it's important to enforce the FK relationships and this schema clearly does that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it had been me, I think I would have had a single `Comments` table with an extra `comment_type_id` field that maps to whether the comment should be available for `customer` entities, `order` entities, etc... Somewhere else you'd need to have a `comment_type` table that `comment_type_id` refers to.

This way, if you decide to add an extra piece of meta-data to comments, you only have to do it in a single `Comments` table rather than in `customer_comments`, `order_comments`, etc...

Comment: The concern I would have with this structure is that it doesn't allow for enforcement of FK relationships.  You have an ambiguous FK field.  I suppose I should have clarified that FK enforcement should be a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

you could put all these comments into one table `comments` and add another column `commented_table`, which would make it a polymorphic ManyToOne. some frameworks / orms (like Rails' ActiveRecord) do have built in support for that, if whatever you're using doesn't, it's basically as simple as adding another `where` clause